# Proof regarding self-adjoint linear operators.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $T : H \rightarrow H$ be a bounded self-adjoint linear operator, with $T \neq 0.$

I need to show that $T^{2^k} \neq 0$  $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Here's what I've done so far:

$T^2x = T(Tx)$ and so $T^{2^k}x = T(T^{2k-1}x)$.
Hence, as T is self-adjoint, $<Tx,y> = <x,T^*y>$ and so $<T^{2k}x,y> = <x,(T^{2k})^*y>$.
However, I'm struggling to go from here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using induction?

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes but I wasn't sure how to approach it. I don't use induction much.

Comment: Can you see why the result is true for $k=0$? Assume it is true for arbitrary $k$ and show it must be true for $k+1$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Just did it for the base case. Not sure how to conclude it for k+1 though.

Comment: Additionally, you should really use self-adjointness. For the equality $\langle Tx,y\rangle=\langle x,T^\ast y\rangle$ you do not need self-adjointness, it's just the definition of the adjoint. But the statement you want to prove does not hold for arbitary bounded operators.

Comment: @MaoWao Ahh I see. I have a theorem stating that if T is self-adjoint then <Tx,x> is real. Will this help?

Comment: Not directly. You just need the definition of self-adjointness here.

Comment: Should I continue with induction? I'm not getting anywhere really.

Comment: In the language of matrices it's very easy---diagonalise $T$, job done. Is there a way of reformulating this in the language of Hilbert spaces?

Comment: @MaoWao I think I've done it by induction. Considering you said you need the fact that T is self adjoint, is induction still a possible method of solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Induction certainly does make this proof go by much smoother.  Here's how one should proceed:

Since $T\neq0$, there is some nonzero $x\in H$ such that $Tx\neq0$. Hence $\|Tx\|>0$, 
$$\langle T^2x,x\rangle=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=\|Tx\|^2>0,$$
and thus $T^2\neq0$. (Can you see how self-adjointness is used? )

For the induction step, just repeat the same proof with $T^{2^k}$ taking the place of $T$.

Comment: I follow this quite well, but how do you get the first $T^2$ from that norm?

Comment: Read it backwards.  Since $\|Tx\|>0$, $\|Tx\|^2>0$, and thus $\langle T^2x,x\rangle>0$.